# vb.net linq to dictionary rounding error

Tags: .net, dictionary, rounding

I have run into something that is really baffling me.  It seems that depending on where I dimension the following dictionary, my value (as Double) is being truncated.

Take the following code:

```
Dim dc As New Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)

While Loop

dc = (From C In dtC.AsEnumerable Where C!ID = .Rows(i).Item("GID")
     Group C By C!DID Into Group
     Select DID, DM =
     Group.Sum(Function(C) CDbl(C!M))).ToDictionary(Function(b) CInt(b.DID), 
     Function(c) c.DM)

Dim testdc As Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Double) = 
(From C In dtC.AsEnumerable Where C!ID = .Rows(i).Item("GID")
Group C By C!DID Into Group
Select DID, DM =
Group.Sum(Function(C) CDbl(C!M))).ToDictionary(Function(b) CInt(b.DID), 
Function(c) c.DM)
```

The results for the dictionary dc are (6,6.3) and (1200,1.9)

The results for dictionary testdc are (6,6.3) and (1200,1.85)

The raw values show 1.9 is actually 1.89999999967 for dc and 1.85 for testdc.

1.85 is the correct value.  Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: GIve us enough code to execute and you might get an answer.

Comment: You definitely should invest attention on variables names to make them more readable/understandable. Especially in cases where we don't have IDE and need to actually read your code

Comment: Are those `!` symbols correct?  I've never seen that in vb.

Comment: You are converting some values to `double` - `Group.Sum(Function(C) CDbl(C!M))`. What is original type of `C!M`?

Comment: Sorry, I censored by variable names due the proprietary nature of the code, probably unnecessary, but I was playing it safe.  The "!" symbols are correct, they are short hand for C("M") for instance.  If you do not convert the value to a double, it will round to a whole number as a function of the summation. The original type of the data in the datatable are integer and float respectively per their SQL origins.

Comment: Sorry guys, figured it out. It was a different part of the code that was affecting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Another part of the code was monkeying with the values.

Thanks!